# Magento2 product detail page's title showing 404 Not Found Error

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Everything works fine but product detail page's title showing 404 Not Found Error.

Any one faced same error before?

Comment: Could you specify a little? Are you talking about frontend or admin? My guess would be frontend. In that case I had similar issues with importing / migrating product data. There is an extension to regenerate the url rewrites for products that saved my ass more than one time: https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites maybe this helps

Comment: Yes, it is frontend PDP. We already tried the extension but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue and it wasn't a rewrite problem.
Try attaching the debugger to the try/catch in `\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View::execute` since this one does a redirect to noroute in the catch.

In my case, way I found out we made an override for `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product/View.php` where  `$pageConfig->setDescription($this->string->substr(strip_tags($product->getDescription()), 0, 255));`
throws an Exception because $string was declared private in the original and should use `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils` instead.

Anyway, searching for things like `$resultForward->forward('noroute');` and attaching debugger there is a good way to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to any exceptions are throwing while loading the PDP pages. Mostly the error is throwing from vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product/View.php